# Is there possibility to measure response time of POD in K8S, Openshift?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift, prometheus

I can't find any metrics about POD response time and requests per minute. Can I measure it without logging everything on my loadbalancers?

Answer (score 2):

Kubernetes doesn't support response time metrics natively. You can grab them via prometheus if your pod exports them (e.g. you have apache or nginx as front-end controller in the pod). Or you can deploy service mesh with proxies like Istio or Linkerd to collect such metrics: [Linkerd](https://linkerd.io/2/reference/proxy-metrics/) [Istio](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/policy-and-telemetry/metrics/)